# NGXS - How to package an action so that it can be dispatched remotely

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

I was recently looking into peer to peer messaging for a multi-user app. For this purpose i got the idea to send actions from one client to another.

Is it possible to serialize an action?

```
source.connection.send(action); // the type is not in the data?

destination.connection.on("data", data => this.store.dispatch(data))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is official documentation and even a plugin that explains how to do this for [websockets](https://www.ngxs.io/plugins/websocket).

---

The code required do this is however pretty simple, so here is my implementation for something besides web socket.

```js
export class SendAction {
    static readonly type = '[Connection] SendAction';
    public packedAction: any;
    constructor(action: any) {
        const type: string = action.__proto__.constructor.type;
        this.packedAction = { type: type, ...action };
    }
}
```

This will take an action as an argument, extract it's type string and data, and store this into the meta action under packedAction attribute.

In the state you can add a handler that sends the packed action over some connection:

```js
    @Action(SendAction)
    dispatch(context: StateContext<ConnectionModel>, action: SendAction) {
        this.connection.send(action.packedAction);
    }
```

Finally on the receiver you can simply dispatch the transmitted action:

```js
   connection.on('data', this.store.dispatch);
```

To send an action to a client one can simply do:

```js
const action = new SomeAction("some payload");
this.store.dispatch(new SendAction(action));
```

Note that i would recommend filtering actions here, as the remote could dispatch any action defined.